# Is there an archive or a collection of quadratic reciprocity proofs?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

After Pythagorean theorem the quadratic reciprocity has the largest amount of proofs, I heard there are more than 160 proofs of quadratic reciprocity. I have seen a few of these proofs but I was wondering has anyone collected these proofs, or at least a generous amount of them?

Comment: Gauss, who discovered it, gave 6 different proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ;-)

Franz Lemmermeyer did: [https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~flemmermeyer/qrg_proofs.html](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eflemmermeyer/qrg_proofs.html)